# Can someone who doesn't have wise account send money to my wise account?

Tags: wire-transfer

Can I receive money into my USD wise account from someone who doesn't have a wise account.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they would just make a bank transfer to Wise in their local currency and Wise would pass it along to you, based on the account information provided in the reference.

> Receiving money into your account works just like a regular bank account. Just share the account details of the currency you want to be paid to the person or business who wants to pay you.

https://wise.com/help/articles/2898124/how-do-i-receive-money

Comment: Thank you very Much.